# how to change default view size

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am  creating a simle application on iphone.I want to change iphone app to ipad application.how to make it?.

Then how to change view size means Through interface builder..

I can't figure why I cannot resize a UIView in a xib in Interface Builder.

I created a new view XIB in xcode and in the size inspector, the width and height are disabled and grayed out to 320 by 460 I want to change 720 *720

I am creating all the view through Inteface builder ......Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to disable all Simulated metrics for view in interface builder (status bar, top bar, bottom bar) then you will be able to change those values..
It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: i am try to change it..but it has no disable options.it has unspecified,gray,black,Transculent black onle show these options

Answer (score 1):

For those who develop with Xcode 4.5+, there is an extra parameter which should be set to `None`. By default, Xcode will assume using Retina 4 inch screen, set that metric to `None` to enable custom resizing for the view.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the Property of the view.

**IN View Attribute just change the Status Bar value to unspecified.**

Thts it..!!